# How to reseal tire where it meets rim?

Tags: tires

I found a leak on a friend's tire along where it meets the rim. I was hoping it was going to be on the threaded mating surface because then I would just plug it myself and then pump it all at home. Is there any way to fix this all at home without going to a shop that has a tire installation tool? Can I just deflate the tire to the point where I can detach it from the rim and then apply some sealant and pump it back up?

The yellow marks are pointing where the bubbles were coming out at the rim when I did a water test.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can try one of the flat repair product in a can (Fix-a-Flat etc.) They can be a problem with some tire pressure monitoring systems though. The best method is to have a tire shop remove the tire clean the inside of the rim. Then they can apply a product that seals the bead.

Comment: Agreed with the shop method. They only have to pop the bead on the leaking side, which will allow access to the rim for cleaning. Then they can apply their soapy solution or even other method for sealing the bead. Once the rim to bead seal is broken, it's about the only way you can get this to work. No re-balance needed. I doubt using fix-a-flat will work, because it will settle on the outside of the tire and not seal the bead/rim interface. Besides it just being nasty on the inside of the tire, I really don't think it will work in this situation.